# Is there a way to remove the charset from the Content-Type of a jsp in tomcat7?

Tags: tomcat7

After upgrading to tomcat7 I have run into a problem.

There is a client program reading the response from a jsp and it is failing because it does not expect the `Content-Type` header to include `charset`. For some reason tomcat automatically adds the default charset to `Content-Type` and I cannot find a way to suppress this behaviour.

```
<%@page contentType="application/json" %>
<%
    response.getWriter().print("{\"key\": \"value\"}");
%>
```

The response looks like this:

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=3E964B5EA6E85CA4DDFB0DDF653B0297; Path=/test/; Secure; HttpOnly
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1
< Content-Length: 25
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Date: Wed, 13 Nov 2013 14:24:42 GMT
< 
{"key": "value"}
```

At first I thought it was `AddDefaultCharsetFilter` adding it, but it specifically only operates on `text/*`.

(I do agree that the client should be able to handle this situation, but older versions do not, and unfortunately it is not possible to upgrade all clients)

Is there a way to have tomcat just deliver the `Content-Type` without adding charset?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/systemprops.html

#### `org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.ENFORCE_ENCODING_IN_GET_WRITER`

> If this is true then a call to Response.getWriter() if no character
>   encoding has been specified will result in subsequent calls to
>   Response.getCharacterEncoding() returning ISO-8859-1 and the
>   Content-Type response header will include a charset=ISO-8859-1
>   component. (SRV.15.2.22.1)
>
> If not specified, the default specification compliant value of true
>   will be used